# $(window).width() not the same as media query

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I am using Twitter Bootstrap on a project.  As well as the default bootstrap styles I have also added some of my own

```
//My styles
@media (max-width: 767px)
{
    //CSS here
}
```

I am also using jQuery to change the order of certain elements on the page when the width of the viewport is less that 767px.

```
$(document).load($(window).bind("resize", checkPosition));

function checkPosition()
{
    if($(window).width() < 767)
    {
        $("#body-container .main-content").remove().insertBefore($("#body-container .left-sidebar"));
    } else {
        $("#body-container .main-content").remove().insertAfter($("#body-container .left-sidebar"));
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that the width calculated by `$(window).width()` and the width calculated by the CSS doesn't seem to be the same.  When `$(window).width()` returns 767 the css calculates it the viewport width as 751 so there seems to be a 16px different.

Does anyone know what is causing this and how I could solve the problem? People have suggested that the width of the scrollbar isn't being taken into considering and using `$(window).innerWidth() < 751` is the way to go.  However ideally I want to find a solution that calculates the width of the scrollbar and that is consistent with my media query (e.g where both conditions are checking against the value 767).  Because surely not all browsers will have a scrollbar width of 16px?

Comment: Try something if ($('html').width() <= 767) {
    // Do something
  }

Comment: @Vaibs_Cool Thanks for the suggestion but I still get the same result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS media queries and JavaScript window width do not match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309859/css-media-queries-and-javascript-window-width-do-not-match)

Comment: Answer i here [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309859/css-media-queries-and-javascript-window-width-do-not-match

Comment: Does "document.documentElement.clientWidth" (instead of "$(window).width()") work how you are wanting it to work? Edit: My mistake, just saw Vaibs_Cool's answer.

Comment: What browser/os are you testing this on?

Comment: You may be looking for **outerWidth**. See my comment below.

Comment: I just answered this question over here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161304/how-to-reliably-get-screen-width-with-the-scrollbar/23159528#23159528

Comment: Hey I answered this same question over here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161304/how-to-reliably-get-screen-width-with-the-scrollbar/23159528#23159528

Comment: scrollbar is 16px btw...

Comment: The best solution on this site is from NateS. Moderniyer and other solutions looks like morons against it.

Answer (score 325, accepted):

If you don't have to support IE9 you can just use `window.matchMedia()` ([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia)).

```
function checkPosition() {
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```

`window.matchMedia` is fully consistent with the CSS media queries and the browser support is quite good: http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia

### UPDATE:

If you have to support more browsers you can use [Modernizr's mq method](http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq), it supports all browsers that understand media queries in CSS.

```
if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 767px)')) {
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```

Comment: If you can afford to use the Modernizr library, this is the best answer out there.

Comment: This solution is better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19292035/1136132 (2nd code). Only JS.

Comment: @joseantgv My solution is also js-only. Can you explain why the solution you linked to is better?

Comment: @ausi no need to extra library (Modernizr) and cross browser, not only IE9+

Comment: @joseantgv The solution you linked to isn’t consistent with the CSS media queries in all browsers, that’s what my answer is all about. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291873/window-width-not-the-same-as-media-query/19292035#comment47998659_19292035

Comment: Can confirm using jquery's innerWidth is still not capturing my css breakpoints in chrome

Comment: Does Modernizr.mq() fire off automatically on window resizing/orientation changing? Or do you have to put window.resize() / orientation change yourself? I checked the docs, but didn't see anything

Comment: @edwardm `Modernizr.mq` only returns a boolean value, so you have to call it yourself in an `onresize` event handler.

Comment: The solution mentionned by NateS is way better. Doesn't need Modernizer and is compatible with every browser supporting media queries.

Comment: @Bernig The solution from NateS is the same technique that is used by `Modernizr.mq`, but Modernizr uses `window.matchMedia` on modern browsers which is the recommended way.

Comment: @ausi right, but media queries having better browser support than matchMedia (not only for IE9), I don't see the point in using two techniques (for old and modern browsers) instead of one that works for both.

Cf. http://caniuse.com/#search=CSS3%20Media%20Queries and http://caniuse.com/#search=matchMedia

So still, I'd choose the simple yet effective version over the Modernizr one if we can avoid using it. But could you please ellaborate on why it is the recommended way (and by who) ? Thanks

Comment: @Bernig `window.matchMedia` is the recommended way, because it doesn’t trigger a [reflow](http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/), depending on how often you call the function this can cause a performance problem. If you don’t want to use Modernizr directly, you can copy the source code from [src/mq.js](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/5eea7e2a213edc9e83a47b6414d0250468d83471/src/mq.js) and [src/injectElementWithStyles.js](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/5eea7e2a213edc9e83a47b6414d0250468d83471/src/injectElementWithStyles.js).

Comment: What if I need a width between sizes? Is `window.matchMedia('(min-width: 568px)').matches && window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches` working?

Comment: @KurtLagerbier Yes, that would work, but you could also use a simpler method and combine both media query like so:  
`window.matchMedia('(min-width: 568px) and (max-width: 767px)').matches`

Comment: Then the next question would be "Won't it be a headache to keep the CSS in JS and the bare CSS consistent"? E.g., what if you change something in CSS and forget to change the same property in the corresponding JS?

Comment: If you want to respond to a media query based style change in the JavaScript I would use `getComputedStyle()` inside a `resize` event to check what the actual style is you are interested in.

Answer (score 192):

Check a CSS rule that the media query changes. This is guaranteed to always work.

http://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    ...
    <div id="mobile-indicator"></div>
</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function isMobileWidth() {
    return $('#mobile-indicator').is(':visible');
}
```

**CSS:**

```
#mobile-indicator {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #mobile-indicator {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a more elegant solution than the JS hacks mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: +1 this is just clever. I like how if you want to change the breakpoints all you have to do is change the css and not javascript.

Comment: This solution works fine and I find it more elegant than the javascript hack proposed in the most voted answer.

Comment: If you use bootstrap you can do it without css like `<div id="xs-indicator" class="xs-visible">`

Answer (score 33):

It may be due to `scrollbar`, use `innerWidth` instead of `width` like

```
if($(window).innerWidth() <= 751) {
   $("#body-container .main-content").remove()
                                .insertBefore($("#body-container .left-sidebar"));
} else {
   $("#body-container .main-content").remove()
                                .insertAfter($("#body-container .left-sidebar"));
}
```

Also you can get the `viewport` like

```
function viewport() {
    var e = window, a = 'inner';
    if (!('innerWidth' in window )) {
        a = 'client';
        e = document.documentElement || document.body;
    }
    return { width : e[ a+'Width' ] , height : e[ a+'Height' ] };
}
```

Above code **[Source](http://andylangton.co.uk/blog/development/get-viewport-size-width-and-height-javascript)**

Comment: Thanks.  This will work but is there anyway I can use jquery to include the width of the scrollbar.  I'm just thinking that the width of the scrollbar could change on different browsers?

Comment: Yes use `innerWidth()` or you can use it like `$('body').innerWidth();` See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339377/jquery-how-to-get-screen-width-without-scrollbar

Comment: You mean window.innerWidth, not on the jQuery $(window) object, $(window).width() returns it incorrectly

Comment: `window.innerWidth` isn’t consistent with CSS media queries in Safari 8 if scrollbars are enabled in the OSX system preferences.

Answer (score 9):

yes, that's due to scrollbar. Right answer source: [enter link description here](http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/get-viewport-size-javascript/)

```
function viewport() {
    var e = window, a = 'inner';
    if (!('innerWidth' in window )) {
        a = 'client';
        e = document.documentElement || document.body;
    }
    return { width : e[ a+'Width' ] , height : e[ a+'Height' ] };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's maybe a better practice not to JS-scope the document's width but some sort of change made by css @media query. With this method you can be sure the JQuery function and css change happens at the same time.

**css:**

```
#isthin {
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
    #isthin {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

**jquery:**

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    isntMobile = $('#isthin').is(":visible");
    ...
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    isntMobile = $('#isthin').is(":visible");
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Use

> window.innerWidth

This solved my problem

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem recently - also with Bootstrap 3.

Neither $.width() nor $.innerWidth() will work for you.

The best solution I came up with - and is specifically tailored to BS3 - 
is to **check the width of a `.container` element.**

As you probably know how the `.container` element works, 
*it's the only element that will give you the current width set by BS css rules.*

So it goes something like

```
bsContainerWidth = $("body").find('.container').width()
if (bsContainerWidth <= 768)
    console.log("mobile");
else if (bsContainerWidth <= 950)
    console.log("small");
else if (bsContainerWidth <= 1170)
    console.log("medium");
else
    console.log("large");
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative to the methods mentioned earlier that rely on changing something via CSS and reading it via Javascript. This method does not need `window.matchMedia` or Modernizr. It also needs no extra HTML element. It works by using a HTML pseudo-element to 'store' breakpoint information:

```
body:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 20em) {
  body:after {
    content: "mobile";
  }
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  body:after {
    content: "tablet";
  }
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  body:after {
    content: "desktop";
  }
}
```

I used `body` as an example, you can use any HTML element for this. You can add any string or number you want into the `content` of the pseudo-element. Doesn't have to be 'mobile' and so on.

Now we can read this information from Javascript in the following way:

```
var breakpoint = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('body'), ':after').getPropertyValue('content').replace(/"/g,'');

if (breakpoint === 'mobile') {
    doSomething();
}
```

This way we are always sure that the breakpoint information is correct, since it is coming directly from CSS and we don't have to hassle with getting the right screen-width via Javascript.

Comment: You don't need to use `querySelector()` or `getPropertyValue()`. You can look for single quote to in regex too (since it's not consistent). This: `window.getComputedStyle(document.body, ':after').content.replace(/"|'/g, '')`. And, to make that a bit less expensive, you can wrap it in underscore/lodash `._debounce()` with ~100ms wait. Finally, appending attribs to <html> makes output available to other things such as tooltip disable clauses looking for raw flags/data outside vars. Example: https://gist.github.com/dhaupin/f01cd87873092f4fe2fb8d802f9514b1

Answer (score 2):

Javascript provides more than one method to check the viewport width. As you noticed, innerWidth doesn't include the toolbar width, and toolbar widths will differ across systems. There is also the **outerWidth** option, which will include the toolbar width. The [Mozilla Javascript API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.outerWidth) states:

> Window.outerWidth gets the width of the outside of the browser window.
>   It represents the width of the whole browser window including sidebar
>   (if expanded), window chrome and window resizing borders/handles.

The state of javascript is such that one cannot rely on a specific meaning for outerWidth in every browser on every platform.

`outerWidth` is [not well supported on **older** mobile browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/03/windowouterwidt.html), though it enjoys support across major desktop browsers and most newer smart phone browsers.

As ausi pointed out, `matchMedia` would be a great choice as CSS is better standardised (matchMedia uses JS to read the viewport values detected by CSS). But even with accepted standards, retarded browsers still exist that ignore them (IE < 10 in this case, which makes matchMedia not very useful at least until XP dies).

In **summary**, if you are only developing for desktop browsers and newer mobile browsers, outerWidth should give you what you are looking for, with [some caveats](http://tripleodeon.com/2011/12/first-understand-your-screen).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a less involved trick to deal with media queries. Cross browser support is a bit limiting as it doesn't support mobile IE.

```
     if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 694px)').matches)
    {
        //do desired changes
    }
```

See [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia.) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround that always works and is synced with CSS media queries.

Add a div to body

```
<body>
    ...
    <div class='check-media'></div>
    ...
</body>
```

Add style and change them by entering into specific media query

```
.check-media{
    display:none;
    width:0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .check-media{
         width:768px;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in JS check style that you are changing by entering into media query

```
if($('.check-media').width() == 768){
    console.log('You are in (max-width: 768px)');
}else{
    console.log('You are out of (max-width: 768px)');
}
```

So generally you can check any style that is being changed by entering into specific media query.

Answer (score 0):

The best cross-browser solution is to use Modernizr.mq

***link:***  https://modernizr.com/docs/#mq

Modernizr.mq allows for you to programmatically check if the current browser window state matches a media query.

```
var query = Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 900px)');
if (query) {
   // the browser window is larger than 900px
}
```

**Note** The browser does not support media queries (e.g. old IE) mq will always return false.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches)
    {
        $(".article-item").text(function(i, text) {

            if (text.length >= 150) {
                text = text.substring(0, 250);
                var lastIndex = text.lastIndexOf(" ");     
                text = text.substring(0, lastIndex) + '...'; 
            }

            $(this).text(text);

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
getData(){
    if(window.innerWidth <= 768) {
      alert('mobile view')
      return;
    }

   //else function will work

    let body= {
      "key" : 'keyValue'
    }
    this.dataService.getData(body).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.myData = data
      }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What i do ;

```
<body>
<script>
function getWidth(){
return Math.max(document.body.scrollWidth,
document.documentElement.scrollWidth,
document.body.offsetWidth,
document.documentElement.offsetWidth,
document.documentElement.clientWidth);
}
var aWidth=getWidth();
</script>
...
```

and call aWidth variable anywhere afterwards.

You need to put the getWidth() up in your document body to make sure that the scrollbar width is counted, else scrollbar width of the browser subtracted from getWidth().

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 767) {
   // scripts
}
```

For More Reference click **[here](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/08/combining_media.html)**

Comment: Thanks, this still has the same result though

Answer (score -2):

Implementation slick slider and display different numbers of slides in the block depending on the resolution (jQuery)

```
   if(window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches) {
      $('.view-id-hot_products .view-content').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        dots: true,
      });
    }

    if(window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1024px)').matches) {
      $('.view-id-hot_products .view-content').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4,
        dots: true,
      });
    }
```