# Only execute jQuery on a small viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jQuery script collapses content, makes title elements clickable, and shows content. I want to constrain the script to viewports smaller than 700 px.

Here is a codepen with the jQuery:

http://codepen.io/paulbremer/pen/AnyDd?editors=001

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291873/window-width-not-the-same-as-media-query

Comment: No, not at all. I tried using the resize() function but the click function gets called on every resize event. I'd like to see how you could only execute the click event on small viewports.

Comment: I updated the codepen, added the resize function, the problem is that if you resize the viewport a few times the click function gets called all the times you resizes the viewport.

Comment: Chances are that any user less than 700px will be on a mobile device and thus trigger onload. Whilst it is nice to be able to randomly resize the window on a larger screen, will any of your users realistically be using the mobile version on a desktop/laptop?

Comment: You've got a point there, I thought I could make it work on the resize() function and make it work on mobile and desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$( window ).width();` to find the width of the window and then only execute when the width is less than 700px.

Demo - http://codepen.io/guyfedwards/pen/aBChg

If you want it to update as the window is resized you could use .resize().
e.g:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 700){  
        // do something
    }   
});
```

Comment: What happen if user resize window?

Comment: This works but only on load and not if you resize the viewport, is it possible to use the resize() function and check the width?

Comment: This will only work onload but the question doesn't specify that. You could use .resize() for it to work as its resized.

Comment: @OP You said viewports, not windows.  I wonder if this is really the correct targeting.  Can you please verify that?