# css media queries and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

I have a project that has a horizontal jquery image carousel. The site is responsive and the carousel needs to have the images get slightly smaller at a certain screen width. I have been able to accomplish this within the css, but the carousel plugin has some javascript settings that I need to change to complete the responsiveness. I have figured out how to work in a media query to get the javascript to change appropriately on page load, but it does not work on resize. Every time I try to include code to change the images on resize the code breaks. Can anybody please help me adapt this code to also work on resize?...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(window).load(function(){

  if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 860) {

    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      animationLoop: false,
      itemWidth: 120,
      itemMargin: 5,
      pausePlay: false,
      start: function(slider){
        $('body').removeClass('loading');
      }
    });
    } 

    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      animationLoop: false,
      itemWidth: 160,
      itemMargin: 5,
      pausePlay: false,
      start: function(slider){
        $('body').removeClass('loading');
      }
    });

  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/Kft2A/5/)**

Try this;

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 860) {
        // scripts here
    }
});
```

Check this out:

[$(window).width() not the same as media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291873/window-width-not-the-same-as-media-query)

According to your comment

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/J7GHJ/1/)**

```
var width = $(window).width();
if ((width < 860)) {
alert('Do first action');
} else {
alert('Do Second action');
}
```

good luck!

Comment: I used the other stack question that you referenced to help me get to where I am at currently, but unfortunately this answer leaves me in a similar but opposite position. This works well on resize, but not onload.

Comment: @John i have updated the answer is that what you want?

Comment: I am still having similar problems, If you care to take a look, here is the carousel... http://weirdesigns.com/carousel/  Try resizing, then refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of clientWidth,

```
if (screen.width < 860) {....}
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but this does not work. The full size setup still works, but the reduced size doesnt work on load or resize now.

Comment: Yes, in media query itself you have options like max/min width. By specifying that size limits we can obtain responsiveness.

Comment: The media queries in the css are working fine, it is solely the javascript that is a problem. I can make the javascript work onload or resize, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (screen.width < 860) {
        // i dont know if Im helping.
    }
});
```

Comment: well... you should do a `$(document).ready(function(){if (screen.width < 860) {
        // i dont know if Im helping.
    }})` also.

Answer (score 0):

Bind to them using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(window).on("load resize",function(){
    // your code
});
```

**Edit**

Try using

```
$(window).bind("load resize", function(e) {
 // your code
});
```

Alternatively, instead of using .bind() you can use .on() as bind directly maps to on().

```
$(window).on("load resize", function(e) {
 // your code
});
```

`function(e)` it's the `event` object. You can read about it [here](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event)

Your final result like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(window).on("load resize",function(e){

  if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 860) {

    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      animationLoop: false,
      itemWidth: 120,
      itemMargin: 5,
      pausePlay: false,
      start: function(slider){
        $('body').removeClass('loading');
      }
    });
    } 

    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      animationLoop: false,
      itemWidth: 160,
      itemMargin: 5,
      pausePlay: false,
      start: function(slider){
        $('body').removeClass('loading');
      }
    });

  });

</script>
```

Comment: Sigh, I had high hopes for this as it looks like what Ive been trying to write to no avail. Unfortunately, it functions exactly as my current code does. Works great on load or refresh, not on resize. Tomorrow Ill work on putting something live to look at, maybe that will help.

Comment: Im still having similar issues. Ill look into the resources youve supplied. Ive included a link above if you care to take a look at the carousel.

Answer (score 0):

Use $(document).ready(function() inside the window.resize() function.

I think problem is that @media-query and window.resize() are not synchronised. *window.resize()* should work after the media-query has done it work. hence use **include $(document).ready(function()** inside the window.resize(), then write  your condition.