# $(window).resize function in live time

Tags: jquery

I have this problem, I need `script` should work in live time
when I resize browser window less than 340px alert window is less than 340px 
and it should happened only one time when `$(window)` size is less then 340px or more 340px
it should be every resize less then 340px or more

```
if($(window) < 340){
     alert("window is less than 340px");
    }else{
    alert("123");
    }
```

Comment: Use CSS media queries for styling purpose or `window.matchMedia` inside window resize handler

Comment: I need change structure of page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make this check whenever the window is resized. For that, there is the `resize` event.

You also need to test the width of the `window`, you can get this using the `.width()` method.

I've changed `alert()` for `console.log()` since this functionality will be invoked every time the cursor moves even a pixel whilst resizing. `alert()` will remove your cursor focus.

I've also triggered the `resize` event after attaching an event handler to have this function run the initial page load.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var $win = $(this);
    if($win.width() < 340){
        console.log("window is less than 340px");
    } else {
        console.log("123");
    }
}).resize();
```

Comment: I need resize happened only one time if window size is less than 340px and if more than 340px `alert("some text")` and this function should happen every time when window is less then 340px or more then 340px

Comment: Be aware to check width, it is usually better to use `window.matchMedia` (&polyfill) or to check using e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21351445/1414562

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
if($( window ).width() < 340){
alert("window is less than 340px");
}else{
console.log('more 340px');
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the Jquery $(window).resize() function

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() < 340){
         alert("window is less than 340px");
    }
    else{
        alert("123");
    }
});
```