# How to convert this media query to jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I want to write jquery code that when my website load via mobile devices show all sub menu .This code exist into Bootstrap.css file. Please advice.

```
        @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {         
      ul.nav li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu{ display: block; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind `$(window).width()` and the width calculated by the CSS is not same because of the scrollbar, in some cases `.innerWidth` will work but yeah that is also something not to be dependent upon.

If IE9 support is not required then you can just use `window.matchMedia()` ([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia)).

```
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches) {
        $("ul.nav li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu").show();
    } else {
        $("ul.nav li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu").hide();
    }
```

`window.matchMedia` is fully consistent with the CSS media queries and the browser support is quite good: http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia

#### Using Modernizr:

Modernizr is a JS based library, if you have to support more browsers you can use [Modernizr's mq method](http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq), it supports all browsers that understand media queries in CSS.

```
if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 768px)')) {
    $("ul.nav li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu").show();
} else {
    $("ul.nav li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu").hide();
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22708436/1496715)

Comment: This is a power full answer. Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

Best solution in this article : http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/

```
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 500px)" );
if (mq.matches) {
    // window width is at least 500px
}
else {
    // window width is less than 500px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($(window).width() <= 768){
    $('ul.nav li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'block');
}
```