# Getting inconsistent results from window.innerWidth in Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari

I'm using this javascript to detect the browser width:

`$(document).ready(function(){
    var width = window.innerWidth;
});`

It appears to be giving inconsistent results. [I've made a working codepen here](http://codepen.io/meanspa/pen/adpevq). by repeatedly refreshing the [full-page view](http://codepen.io/meanspa/full/adpevq/) in mobile Safari I've received both of the following results:

[image: ios9 Mobile Safari window.innerWidth]
[image: ios9 Mobile Safari window.innerWidth]

It jumps back and forth inconsistently, and appears to be exacerbated by a larger page size (hence all the images). Sometimes it will only return one result until I kill the app and re-open it.

Is there a better way to get the width of the browser?

Notes:

- I've added this to the head: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />`
- Using `$(window).width()` isn't really an option for me because it doesn't account for scrollbars
- I know I could put the js in a timeout function, but this solution is problematic for me since I'm storing the result in a variable that I'm using in various places throughout the website.
- I'm using an iPhone 5 running iOS 9.2

Thanks!

Comment: One quick note - I recognize some variation of this question has been asked several times before, but so far I haven't found a solution that actually adresses my criteria. Appoligies if I'm wrong about that though!

Comment: Update: Not a direct answer to this question, but thought I would mention that I did find some great workarounds here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291873

Answer (score 1):

Safari gets inconsistent widths in vanilla javascript because of the resolution. JQuery usually standardised this. Try using:

```
$(window).width()
```

This should give you the right width.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However it looks like jQuery.com says re:innerWidth - "This method is not applicable to window and document objects; for these, use .width() instead."

Comment: Sorry, meant to put `width()`, I copied it from your question :)

Comment: I just re-read your question, and saw you mention not wanting to use `width()`. However, in my experience this is the only way I have been able to get a definitive width on all browsers. If your issue is deducting the scrollbars from the page width, you might find this solution useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986937/how-can-i-get-the-browsers-scrollbar-sizes

Comment: If I end up needing to go that route that will be helpful, thanks!