# How to hide(disable) anything from desktop to mobile css transition

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I want to use `@media` to "hide" some block elements from the desktop version to mobile, so the "hidden" elements won't eat traffic.

This "block elements" will obviously contain many data, including images, inline block elements, block elements etc. All this should not downloaded in the mobile version. And well, I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve this with the `@media` rule. As far as I can tell, the `display: none` doesn't solve this problem, but perhaps I'm wrong.

P.S. code example:

```
<div class="desktop">
 ...
 <div ... > ... </div>
 <span ... > ... </span>
 ...
</div>
<div class="mobile">
 ...
 <div ... > ... </div>
 <span ... > ... </span>
 ...
</div>

@media (max-width:799px){
  .desktop { display: none; }
}
@media (min-width:800px){
  .mobile { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: Can I see the code which you want to hide including a jsFiddle link with the code in issue?

Comment: Thanks for down-voting without a reason :)

Comment: Nathan L, it can be really anything. But I don't mind to give an example, sure

Comment: Have you added <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> in your header of the html class? If not check this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859336/css3-media-queries-not-working

Comment: sure I did. it's not about that `@media` not working, it works perfectly. It's about hiding some elements with it, so it won't eat bandwidth

Comment: You should use JQuery or Javascript to generate the HTML parts on mobile or desktop, see the answer on this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291873/window-width-not-the-same-as-media-query

Comment: Your code should works well. Do you have a particular HTML that produces the behaviour that you explain in your question?

Comment: Pascal... What? How is this question related to what was discussed in the link you provided?

Comment: Error404, it's not pal. I mean look at here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158540/does-displaynone-prevent-an-image-from-loading  I'm not the only one with this problem... Moreover, I'm not looking for just to prevent img from loading, but everything else too

Comment: @bogiwa It was too difficult to explain in only a few words, so I gave an answer, I hope my answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Elements are loaded even with a `display:none` (they are loaded but not displayed), you could use JQuery to generate some parts of your website:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
        $("#mobile" ).html("mobile!");
    } else {
         $("#desktop" ).html("desktop!");
    }
 });
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>

<div id="mobile"></div>
<div id="desktop"></div>
```

On mobile the HTML code would looks like this :

```
<div id="mobile">Mobile!</div>
<div id="desktop"></div>
```

On Desktop like this :

```
<div id="mobile"></div>
<div id="desktop">Desktop</div>
```

I don't know if there's a better solution, but I hope my answer will help you.