# targeting a specific nav div in code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code which applies classes to the `<nav>` element. The code works so no issues there.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
        $('nav').addClass('stick');
        $('nav').css('top','0');
    }

    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 300) {
        $('nav').removeClass('stick');
        $('nav').css('top', '0');
    }

});

});
```

however I use two  elements in my website so I only want the code to apply to this specific nav

html

```
<nav role="main-navigation">   ...  </nav>
```

As well, I would also like the code to ONLY apply to this `nav` element on screens >768px

Comment: you could use ids and target using `$('#idName')`

Comment: You could also target with `$('nav[role="main-navigation"]')`

Comment: _“As well, I would also like the code to ONLY apply to this nav element on screens >768px”_ - well then wrap it in a condition that checks the current window width ...

Comment: I wasn't sure if I needed to apply that condition around the entire function or inside based on the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ "Want the code to apply to this specific nav "
If you don't want to add more attribute (id, class) you can use [Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$("nav[role='main-navigation']").
```

2/ "ONLY apply to this nav element on screens >768px"
Reference to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291873/window-width-not-the-same-as-media-query)

```
if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)').matches) {
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the $(nav[ ] ) but it works thanks

Answer (score 1):

`$('nav')[0]`  --> it identifies specific nav tag.. without using id we can specify like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
        $('nav')[0].addClass('stick');
        $('nav')[0].css('top','0');
    }

    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 300) {
        $('nav')[0].removeClass('stick');
        $('nav')[0].css('top', '0');
    }

});

});
```