# Zurb Foundation Accordion Closing by Itself on Mobile

Tags: zurb-foundation

On phones, my "Section Menu" closes by itself after the user opens and starts scrolling. I'm using a Zurb Foundation Accordion for the menu. Does anyone know why this is happening on mobile?

UPDATE: I'm also trying a simple Zurb Foundation Toggler. I'm toggling the ".hide" class. The menus still vanish when the user tries to scroll.

My site:
https://deq.utah.gov/communication/public-notices

[picture of the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYtRi.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was using the following script to listen for widow size changes. This helped me show/hide my menu when troubleshooting on a desktop browser. For some reason, mobile was reporting a screen width change on scroll. When I removed this script, my accordion stopped closing by itself.

[$(window).width() not the same as media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291873/window-width-not-the-same-as-media-query)