# Disable jQuery as per the screen size

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following `jQuery` code.

```
$(".item").hover(function(){
  $(this).find('.item-hover').css("display","block");
  }, function(){
  $(this).find('.item-hover').css("display","none");
});
```

I want this `jQuery` code to work only if the screen size is bigger than 768.

I tried the following method but it didn't helped me.

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
   if ($(this).width() >= 768) {
    $(".item").hover(function(){
      $(this).find('.item-hover').css("display","block");
      }, function(){
      $(this).find('.item-hover').css("display","none");
    });
  }
```

Comment: Don't use JS for this. You should be using CSS Media Queries instead

Comment: thanks @RoryMcCrossan . ill try it from css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you are attaching your `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` handlers every time the window is resized, you don't want to do that.

You need only check the width of the window when the `mouseenter` event handler itself is invoked.

Another note: use `window.matchMedia()` rather than checking `$(window).width()`, as the [latter cannot always be relied on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19291873/1612146):

```
$(".item").hover(function(){
    if(window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)').matches){
        $(this).find('.item-hover').css("display","block");
    }
}, function(){
    $(this).find('.item-hover').css("display","none");
});
```

Having said that, as [already highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298841/disable-jquery-as-per-the-screen-size/55299012#comment97326116_55298841), (assuming you don't need it for functionality not described here) you needn't use JavaScript at all for this. A little CSS alone will do the job:

```
.item .item-hover{
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
    .item:hover .item-hover{
        display: block;
    }
}
```