# How to make sure query animate works on all screen sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I developed a basic html website with some animations using jquery. However I have to re-design for smaller screen sizes. My current code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Animation for Flower Logo
  $('.flogo').animate({
    width: '350px',
    height: '300px'
  }, 1000);
});
```

If I try using jquery for screen sizes the animation stops working. For example:

```js
// Animation for Flower Logo
$(document).ready(function() {
  var targetWidth = 768;
  if ($(window).width() &gt;= targetWidth) {
    $('.flogo').animate({
      width: '350px',
      height: '300px'
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    $('.flogo').animate({
      width: '300px',
      height: '300px'
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

Comment: `&gt;=` needs to be `<=`. Also note that if you want to make an animation work for any screen size, use a relative width, eg `%`, `vmin`, `vmax`, `vh` or `vw`

Comment: Glad to help. Also note that this can also be done with CSS alone using media queries, which will also perform much better than this JS.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But this was just a small section of the complete animation code on the page and CSS alone was not enough. But I changed most of the code to % and it helped me clean up a lot of junk code. Thank you very much for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To address multiple screen sizes, you can use **[css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries)** as they are designed for that purpose.

> Media queries let you adapt your site or app depending on the presence
>   or value of various device characteristics and parameters.
>
> They are a key component of responsive design. For example, a media
>   query can shrink the font size on small devices, increase the padding
>   between paragraphs when a page is viewed in portrait mode, or bump up
>   the size of buttons on touchscreens.

Note that you may encounter a popular issue dealing with width. You can easily find solutions online.
[$(window).width() not the same as media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291873/window-width-not-the-same-as-media-query)