# Media Queries and JQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, media-queries

I'm trying to get the figures in this jQuery code to change based on the screen size, in particular the amount I multiply the window by. Is this possible?

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function() { //Slides Bio into view
  $('h2').css("left", Math.max(2000 - 1 * window.scrollY, 100) + "px");
})
```

Comment: take a look of this https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/

Comment: I searched for the exact title of your question and found an answer here on SO with many approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291873/window-width-not-the-same-as-media-query